Deploy Nestjs microservice on Vercel
I have three microsrvices, and the project structure is:
.
├── client
│   ├── src
├── auth
│   ├── src
├── chat
│   ├── src
├── libs
│   ├── common
└── README.md
├── package.json

And all the routes are in Client app.
I deployed three projects for each app on Vercel.
Here is the screenshot of one service:

After build them, I got this error in other two projects:

The problem is, these project shouldn't listen to any port, and also, they should  only run their own app. But accroding to this screenshot(this is screenshot for auth apps), Vercel build Client app as well.
I wonder what should I do to build them correctly?
